# Plex view date history for Recently Played Movies

Tags: date, plex

Plex has a list of your "Recently Played Movies" and "Recently Played Episodes":

[image: Recently Played Movies]

How can I view exactly *when* these movies were watched? Where can I see the play **date** of the Plex items I have watched?

Answer (score 1):

The last play date is encoded in the Media Info XML for any Plex item.

> Plex item > Get Info > View XML

The `lastViewedAt` key in the Plex item XML is the Unix time timestamp of the most recent play history.

```
lastViewedAt="1613795574"
```

<sub>Note: this **View XML** functionality may only be available to Plex Server admins, not viewing users.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

You can hover over the simple date. The exact date is shown as a tooltip.